# How is conflict resolution calculated in Castle Vox?

Tags: castle-vox

The help file for [Castle Vox](http://sillysoft.net/vox/) is vague:

> Conflicts are resolved by the game according to the attack/defend values of the units
> involved.

And here's all it says about the attack/defend values:

> The pawn has a strong defensive value, but a weak attacking value.
>
> knight has a weak defensive value, but a strong attacking value.
>
> Castles provides an extra defensive bonus.

It doesn't give specific numbers , if there are any other factors (such as a random die roll), or what formula it uses to crunch the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Castle Vox conflict resolution details are described here:
http://sillysoft.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=19387